# 400 error on simple count aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to do a simple count on a field in elastic search but keep getting a 400 error...

here is my query:

```
curl -XPOST "http://host/logstash-2016.05.19/_search" -d'
{
   "aggregations": {
      "the_name": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "serviceName"
         },
         "aggregations": {
            "callcnt": {
               "count": {
                  "field": "requestId"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

and this is the error I get back:

```
{
   "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[ZWtovPXtTfSuJzg9M3FMjw][logstash-2016.05.19][0]: RemoteTransportException[[es4][inet[/10.149.76.55:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2016.05.19][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"aggregations\": {\n      \"the_name\": {\n         \"terms\": {\n            \"field\": \"serviceName\"\n         },\n         \"aggregations\": {\n            \"callcnt\": {\n               \"count\": {\n                  \"field\": \"requestId\"\n               }\n            }\n         }\n      }\n   }\n}\n]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2016.05.19][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Could not find aggregator type [count] in [callcnt]]]; }{[vSqpHGQXRf6OUIEF_kQ1jg][logstash-2016.05.19][1]: RemoteTransportException[[es2][inet[/10.149.76.138:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2016.05.19][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"aggregations\": {\n      \"the_name\": {\n         \"terms\": {\n            \"field\": \"serviceName\"\n         },\n         \"aggregations\": {\n            \"callcnt\": {\n               \"count\": {\n                  \"field\": \"requestId\"\n               }\n            }\n         }\n      }\n   }\n}\n]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2016.05.19][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Could not find aggregator type [count] in [callcnt]]]; }{[PwDi_CIiQHmOHp34KdWk0A][logstash-2016.05.19][2]: RemoteTransportException[[es3][inet[/10.149.76.97:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2016.05.19][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"aggregations\": {\n      \"the_name\": {\n         \"terms\": {\n            \"field\": \"serviceName\"\n         },\n         \"aggregations\": {\n            \"callcnt\": {\n               \"count\": {\n                  \"field\": \"requestId\"\n               }\n            }\n         }\n      }\n   }\n}\n]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2016.05.19][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Could not find aggregator type [count] in [callcnt]]]; }{[PwDi_CIiQHmOHp34KdWk0A][logstash-2016.05.19][3]: RemoteTransportException[[es3][inet[/10.149.76.97:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2016.05.19][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"aggregations\": {\n      \"the_name\": {\n         \"terms\": {\n            \"field\": \"serviceName\"\n         },\n         \"aggregations\": {\n            \"callcnt\": {\n               \"count\": {\n                  \"field\": \"requestId\"\n               }\n            }\n         }\n      }\n   }\n}\n]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2016.05.19][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Could not find aggregator type [count] in [callcnt]]]; }{[PwDi_CIiQHmOHp34KdWk0A][logstash-2016.05.19][4]: RemoteTransportException[[es3][inet[/10.149.76.97:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2016.05.19][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"aggregations\": {\n      \"the_name\": {\n         \"terms\": {\n            \"field\": \"serviceName\"\n         },\n         \"aggregations\": {\n            \"callcnt\": {\n               \"count\": {\n                  \"field\": \"requestId\"\n               }\n            }\n         }\n      }\n   }\n}\n]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2016.05.19][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Could not find aggregator type [count] in [callcnt]]]; }]",
   "status": 400
}
```

I'm using the Sense chrome extension too to run the queries so not sure if that makes a difference.

New to querying elasticsearch so am trying to follow some guides online but not getting any where far...I can do simple queries successfully, but can't seem to figure out the aggregation ones...

edit:

what I'm trying to do with the aggregation is get something like this back if it was a sql query:

```
select serviceName, count(requestId) as cnt
from tableA
group by serviceName
```

results:

```
serviceName | cnt
-----------------
srvc1          32
srvc3          18
srvc7          75
etc...
```

Comment: Can you repharase what are you trying to achieve through aggregations ?

Comment: @Tanu updated my question with what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no `count` aggregation. The aggregation you need to use is called [`value_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html)

See the error:

> Parse Failure [Could not find aggregator type [count] in [callcnt]]];

Use this instead and it will work:

```
curl -XPOST "http://host/logstash-2016.05.19/_search" -d '{
   "aggregations": {
      "the_name": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "serviceName"
         },
         "aggregations": {
            "callcnt": {
               "value_count": {
                  "field": "requestId"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

**UPDATE**

Following up on your comment, here is how you can do what you need, i.e. use a `terms` sub-aggregation instead of the `value_count` one.

```
curl -XPOST "http://host/logstash-2016.05.19/_search" -d '{
   "aggregations": {
      "the_name": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "serviceName"
         },
         "aggregations": {
            "callcnt": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "requestId"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Comment: Thank @val...that did work but one slight problem, or maybe I asked the question wrong...the results that came back was not what I expected...I esstianlly was expecting the counts of the distinct values in serviceName field....so if I wrote a SQL query, I'd write it like this....select serviceName, count(requestId) from table group by serviceName

Answer (score 1):

Simple use `terms` aggregations to get the counts of the distinct values in `serviceName` field.

```
 curl -XPOST "http://host/logstash-2016.05.19/_search" -d '{
  "aggregations": {.
  "the_name": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "serviceName"
           }
          }
         }
       }'
```

Hope this helps!!!!

Comment: ok...one more thing...what if I wanted a distinct count on serviceName and userName pairing...so if I wrote an sql query...it would look like this: select serviceName, userName, count(requestId) from tableA groupby serviceName, userName....essentially a grouping of serviceName and userName

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be that ElasticSearch searches are made with `GET`, not `POST`. Try `curl -XGET`

Also, there is no `count` aggregation.  Do you mean [`value_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html)?

---

**Tip**: Append `?pretty` to your URL to get output that's easier to read:

```
curl -XGET "http://host/logstash-2016.05.19/_search?pretty"
```